# A determinant of a matrix with binomial coefficients

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients, determinant

Consider the matrix  $$A_n = \left( {a(i,j)} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1}$$ with $$a(i,j) = \binom{(i-j+r)x+s}{n-1}$$ where $r,s$ are arbitrary numbers. 
Is there a simple proof of the following?

$$\det (A_n) = x^{2 \binom{n}{2}}$$

**Edit:**
I don’t know what you consider as relevant. I was only curious if the following determinants are a special case of a more general fact:

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 2&1\\3&2\end{vmatrix}=1^2,\quad
\begin{vmatrix} 3&1\\5&3\end{vmatrix}=2^2,\quad
\begin{vmatrix} 4&1\\7&4\end{vmatrix}=3^2,\dots, \\
\begin{vmatrix} 6&3&1\\10&6&3\\15&10&6\end{vmatrix}=1^6,\quad
\begin{vmatrix} 15&6&1\\28&15&6\\45&28&15\end{vmatrix}=2^6,\quad
\begin{vmatrix} 28&10&1\\55&28&10\\91&55&28\end{vmatrix}=3^6,\dots.
$$

Computer experiments said yes, but I could not find a simple proof.

Comment: Complicated as it looks, $a\left(i,j\right)$ is still just a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $i-j$ (where we treat $r, s, x$ as constants). If you flip the order of the columns, it becomes a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $i+j$. And such a determinant can be found via Exercise 6.17 **(c)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10) (a known formula that probably has its share of m.se threads). All you need is the leading coefficient of the polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Darij Grinberg’s answer led to the following simple proof:

$\binom{x_i-y_j+s}{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{x_i}{k}\binom{s-y_j}{n-1-k}$

implies  $M_n=(\binom{x_i-y_j+s}{n-1})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}=B_nC_n$

with
$B_n=(\binom{x_i}{j})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}$ and $C_n=(\binom{s-y_j}{n-1-i})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}.$

Since $\det(\binom{x_i}{j})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}=\frac{\prod_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}(x_j-x_i)}{ \prod_{0\leq i\leq n-1}(i!)}$ we finally get
$\det(\binom{x_i-y_j+s}{n-1})_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}=\frac{\prod_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}(x_j-x_i) \prod_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}(y_j-y_i)}{ \prod_{0\leq i\leq n-1}(i!)^2}.$

If we choose $x_i=xi+r$ and $y_j=xj$ we get 
$\det (A_n) = x^{2 \binom{n}{2}}.$